# WHERE clause that includes an AND substring condition

Tags: php, mysql

The php query shown far below was working fine till I added this condition to the WHERE clause (the query turned up a blank result after I added it):

```
AND SUBSTR(company_id,1)='1'
```

Basically I want to only include companies for which the last digit in `company_id` is '1'.  How can I do this?

```
$data = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT table1.company_abbrev, table2.company_name FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.company_id=banks.company_id AND SUBSTR(company_id,1)='1' ORDER BY table2.company_name ");
```

Comment: Is company_id a string or some kind of numeric type?

Comment: I've added an answer for you. Isn't it helpful for you?

Answer (score 4):

Just Try this

```
SUBSTR(company_id,-1)='1' 

 SUBSTRING(), the position of the first character in the string from which the 
 substring  is to be extracted is reckoned as 1
```

For More details please see [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

Answer (score 3):

When the position argument to `SUBSTR` is positive, it counts from the beginning of the string. When it's negative, it counts from the end. So you want `SUBSTR(company_id, -1)`. You can also use `RIGHT(company_id, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTR(company_id,1) returns the whole string (starting at index 1, which is the first character)
Just do

```
LIKE '%1'
```

Or

```
SUBSTRING(REVERSE(company_id), 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SUBSTRING('Sakila' FROM -1 FOR 1)='1'
```

The "-" is counted from the last character. and "For 1" means that you take 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

Use like Clause, replace your code with it SUBSTR(company_id,1) like '%1'

Answer (score 0):

If compan_id is a numeric type, such as integer, it will be much faster to do numeric computations on it. Use the modulo operator to isolate the last digit.

```
WHERE company_id % 10 == 1
```